# QTreeWidget findItems or filter by icon

Tags: qt, filter, qtreewidget

I'm using QTreeWidget with icons and strings data.

Right now I'm using my own filter function to filter out string via [QTreeWidget::findItems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#findItems) function and it's works pretty good.

BUT, how can I filter/findItems by icons ?

The Qt findItems functions can get only strings as input...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* findByIcon( QTreeWidget* aTreeWidget, const QIcon& aIcon, const int aColumn = 0 )
{
    QTreeWidgetItemIterator iterator( aTreeWidget );
    while ( *iterator )
    {
        if ( (*iterator)->data( aColumn, Qt::DecorationRole ) == aIcon )
        {
            return (*iterator);
        }
        ++iterator;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

This will find the first match only, is it enough ?

If not then here is a function which finds all the items with the given icon:

```
QList< QTreeWidgetItem* > findByIcon( QTreeWidget* aTreeWidget, const QIcon& aIcon, const int aColumn = 0 )
{
    QList< QTreeWidgetItem* > items;
    QTreeWidgetItemIterator iterator( aTreeWidget );
    while ( *iterator )
    {
        if ( (*iterator)->data( aColumn, Qt::DecorationRole ) == aIcon )
        {
            items << (*iterator);
        }
        ++iterator;
    }
    return items;
}
```